# Skymiles+MQMs on Aeromexico flight booked via Expedia

Tags: expedia, skyteam, aeromexico

Looking to purchase a flight from SFO to Quito on a SkyTeam airline (trying to gain delta status this year!)

On the Delta and Aeromexico websites, the cost is over $1000. However, Expedia has an Aeromexico roundtrip itinerary for under $700.

Do Aeromexico itineraries bought on third-party websites collect MQMs and miles?

Any advice deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MQMs are based on distance flown and fare class, and it doesn't matter where you book the tickets, so long as they aren't sold as an "opaque" ticket, like priceline.com or hotwire.com. Such sites will disclose that you won't earn miles for the booking, and do not tell you the airline you fly on until after you have paid.

The [Program Rules](https://www.delta.com/content/www/en_US/skymiles/program-resources/program-rules.html) state in part that you won't earn any SkyMiles credit of any kind for:

> Bookings made through some Internet sites as described at those sites, including without limitation tickets purchased through priceline.com and Hotwire.com.